# SlideShow with next-previous jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to slideshow with next-previous button with jquery , I followed [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/hHnX5/)
 then I tried to change from `img` to div but it did not work, Here is my code :

```
<% _.each(items, function(item) {
  if (i < 10){ i++; } else { return false; } %>
     <div class="divRecentItem">
            <div style="height:90px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">
                <a href="#itemDetail/<%=item.ID%>">
                    <img src="<%=item.PictureName%>" alt="Item" width="60px">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <a href="<%=item.ID%>"><%=item.Name%></a>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <%=item.PriceShow%>
            </div>
        </div>
<% }); %>
 <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowright.jpg" class="next" alt="Next"/>
 <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowleft.jpg" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>


 $('.divRecentItem .divRecentItem:gt(0)').hide();

 $('.next').click(function() {
     $('.divRecentItem .divRecentItem:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.divRecentItem');
 });

 $('.prev').click(function() {
     $('.divRecentItem .divRecentItem:first-child').fadeOut();
     $('.divRecentItem .divRecentItem:last-child').prependTo('.divRecentItem').fadeOut();
     $('.divRecentItem .divRecentItem:first-child').fadeIn();
 });
```

Comment: The example shows the HTML as a div with a series of images in it. Do you have the same structure? A fiddle might be nice so we can see where the errors are.

Comment: @TimSPQR Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v74PA/

Comment: I haven't given up. Here's an update - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/hHnX5/444/ - I'm working on how to cycle the titles. Difficult.

Comment: Ok. Got the text to move forward http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/hHnX5/445/. Now will work on backward. For text I switched from fadeIn/fadeout to hide/show, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/hHnX5/446/)

Relevant JS

```
$('.img-wrap img:gt(0)').hide();
$('.footertext span:gt(0)').hide();
$('.footerprice span:gt(0)').hide();

$('.next').click(function () {
   $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img-wrap');
   $('.footertext span:first-child').hide().next().show().end().appendTo('.footertext');
   $('.footerprice span:first-child').hide().next().show().end().appendTo('.footerprice');
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:last-child').prependTo('.img-wrap').fadeOut();
    $('.img-wrap img:first-child').fadeIn();

    $('.footertext span:first-child').hide();
    $('.footertext span:last-child').prependTo('.footertext').hide();
    $('.footertext span:first-child').show();

    $('.footerprice span:first-child').hide();
    $('.footerprice span:last-child').prependTo('.footerprice').hide();
    $('.footerprice span:first-child').show();

});
```

It's not perfect by any means, but at least it will give you a start.

The 'teaching point' or the "Eureka" moment for me was realizing that all of the images/text were in a div and kept in a div - just variously hidden(fadeout for img) and shown(fadein for img).

It was a good exercise - I learned a lot. Thanks for the question!

Comment: Thank you so much TimSPQR for pointing that out. It's work well, but should change from `img` to `a` for my code :)